# Linux count how many mails a certain domain sends per date

Tags: shell, awk, command-line, grep, smtp

I have some logs of a Linux SMTP server which uses the postfix agent. I want to perform an operation on the logs so I can know how many mails a certain domain sends per date without writing a script.

For example my **mail.log** file has these contents:

```
Jan  1 14:05:31 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<john@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 78B06EC0073)
Jan  1 15:05:00 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<alice@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 874BE4587C4)
Jan  1 15:05:00 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<fred@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 98C484E1571)
Jan  2 10:08:15 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<luke@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4456D154E12)
Jan  2 15:07:00 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<tyson@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4F54515C154)
Jan  2 14:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<bob@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 9856C984E16)
Feb  1 13:14:35 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<nick@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as EC1874415E8)
```

The output I want is:

**- First the domain/address the mail is sent from**

**- Amount of mails that specific domain sends per date (e.g. Jan 1 2 mails sent)**

So here the output should be somehow:

```
http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25
Jan 1 2
Jan 2 1
Feb 1 1

http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25
Jan 1 1
Jan 2 2
```

For now I know I have 2 commands that can do these operations seperately, but I really have no idea on how to combine them together:

**1. Count how many mails a certain domain sends in total:**

```
[user@linux ~] grep -h "status=sent" mail.log | cut -d' ' -f9 | awk '{c[$0] += 1} END {for(i in c){printf "%6s %4d\n", i, c[i]}}' | sort -M

relay=http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25,    3
relay=http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25,    4
```

**2. Count how many mails are sent per day**

```
[user@linux ~]$ grep -h "status=sent" mail.log | cut -c-6 | awk '{c[$0] += 1} END {for(i in c){printf "%6s %4d\n", i, c[i]}}' | sort -k2

Feb  1    1
Jan  1    3
Jan  2    3
```

Does anyone know a good command that can help me with this specific operation? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Since you have stipulated that you don't want to write a script, this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk` should work with any version.

```
awk '
{
  gsub(/^relay=|,$/,"",$8)
}
{
  arr1[$1 OFS $2 OFS $8]++
}
END{
  for(i in arr1){
    split(i,arr2)
    arr3[arr2[3]]=(arr3[arr2[3]]?arr3[arr2[3]] ORS:"") (arr2[1] OFS arr2[2] OFS arr2[4] OFS arr1[i])
  }
  for(i in arr3){
    print i ORS arr3[i]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** In main program of `awk` firstly globally substituting starting relay= AND ending `,` with NULL in 7th field. Then creating an array named `arr1` which has index as `$1 OFS $2 OFS $8` and keep increasing its count with same indexes with 1 here, doing this for all the lines for Input_file. Then in `END` block of `awk` code, traversing through arr1 all elements and splitting its index `i` into arr2. Then creating new array arr3 with index of arr2's 3 element which is http value in Input_file. And assigning value to `arr2[1] OFS arr2[2] OFS arr2[4] OFS arr1[i]`. Once in all cycles arr3 is created, then traversing through all of its items by for loop and printing its index followed by ORS(new line) followed by value of arr3(which is responsible for printing needed required output).

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- a line can have at most one instance of the string `relay=`
- `relay=` may not always show up in the same spaced-delimited field
- output for a given domain/address should be in calendar order (which in this case should also be the order in which dates are read from `mail.log`)

Adding a couple lines that do not include `relay=`:

```
$ cat mail.log
Jan  1 14:05:31 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<john@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 78B06EC0073)
Jan  1 14:17:27 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<john@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=rejected (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 78B06EC0073)
Jan  1 15:05:00 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<alice@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 874BE4587C4)
Jan  1 15:05:00 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<fred@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 98C484E1571)
Jan  2 10:08:15 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<luke@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4456D154E12)
Jan  2 12:13:31 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<john@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=rejected (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 78B06EC0073)
Jan  2 15:07:00 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<tyson@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4F54515C154)
Jan  2 14:59:11 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<bob@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 9856C984E16)
Feb  1 13:14:35 mail postfix/smtp[31349]: E6EC84105D: to=<nick@example.com>, relay=http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.22/0.05/0.36/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as EC1874415E8)
```

One idea using `GNU awk` (for array of arrays):

```
awk '
BEGIN         { regex = "\\<relay=[^, ]" }

/status=sent/ { date=$1 FS $2
                addr=""

                for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {                     # loop through fields looking for "relay="
                    if ($i ~ regex) {                     # and if found then parse out the domain/address
                       split($i,arr,"=")
                       addr=arr[2]
                       gsub(",","",addr)
                       continue
                    }
                }

                if (addr != "") {                         # if we found an address then increment our counter
                   counts[addr][date]++

                   if (date != prevdate) {                # and keep track of the order in which dates have been processed
                      dates[++dtorder]=date
                      prevdate=date
                   }
                }
              }

END           { for (addr in counts) {
                    print addr

                    for (i=1;i<=dtorder;i++)              # loop through dates[] in the same order in which they were processed
                        if (dates[i] in counts[addr])
                           print dates[i],counts[addr][dates[i]]
                }
              }
' mail.log
```

**NOTES:**

- `for (addr in counts)` is not guaranteed to process array entries in any specific order
- `dates[++dtorder]=date` is used to keep track of the order in which dates are processed; this is then used in the `END{...}` processing to insure we ouput dates in the same order; this assumes dates show up in `mail.log` in calendar order which in turn eliminates the need to figure out how to sort `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar`, etc in calendar order

This generates:

```
http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25
Jan 1 1
Jan 2 2
http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25
Jan 1 2
Jan 2 1
Feb 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact output you want but quite simple (tested with GNU and BSD `awk`, `sort` and `uniq`):

```sh
$ awk -F'=|,?[[:space:]]+' '{print $10,$1,$2}' mail.log | sort | uniq -c
      1 http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25 Feb 1
      2 http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25 Jan 1
      1 http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25 Jan 2
      1 http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25 Jan 1
      2 http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25 Jan 2
```

The `awk` field separator is set by the `-F'=|,?[[:space:]]+'` option to either an `=` sign, or an optional comma followed by at least one space (or tab, formfeed...) According this, the fields you are interested in are number 10 (origin), 1 (month) and 2 (day). `sort | uniq -c` sorts and prints the result, one line per unique input, preceded with the count.

But the sorting of the months is alphabetical. If you want the output to be sorted first by origin and then by increasing date we can add `sort` options:

```sh
$ awk -F'=|,?[[:space:]]+' '{print $10,$1,$2}' mail.log | sort -k1,1 -k2,2M -k3,3 |
  uniq -c
      2 http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25 Jan 1
      1 http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25 Jan 2
      1 http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25 Feb 1
      1 http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25 Jan 1
      2 http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25 Jan 2
```

`-k2,2M` sorts the month names of the second key by date, instead of alphabetically. Finally, if you want the exact output you show, we can add a last `awk` script for the final formatting:

```sh
$ awk -F'=|,?[[:space:]]+' '{print $10,$1,$2}' mail.log | sort -k1,1 -k2,2M -k3,3 |
  uniq -c | awk '$2!=p {p=$2; print (NR!=1) ? "\n" p : p} {print $3,$4,$1}'
http://mail.example.org[127.0.0.1]:25
Jan 1 2
Jan 2 1
Feb 1 1

http://mail.example2.org[127.0.0.1]:25
Jan 1 1
Jan 2 2
```

Each time the origin changes (`$2!=p`) this last `awk` script stores the new origin in variable `p` for later comparisons, prints a newline (except for the first line, thus the `(NR!=1) ? "\n" p : p`), and prints the new origin. For each line it also prints the month (`$3`), the day (`$4`) and the count (`$1`).